# Ceiling fan wiring (2x light switch, 1x fan switch)

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I'm installing a ceiling fan in our kitchen and we need to have 1x switch for the fan (preset fan control switch) and 2x switches for the light (1x 3-pole dimmer switch, 1x 3-pole switch). I was unable to find any wiring diagrams for such a setup, so I drew one up myself:

[image: wiring diagram]

Before implementing it I wanted to get some outside eyes on the diagram to make sure that it will in fact work as intended and that it is safe and to code.

Any help or input would be appreciated. TIA!

*Updated diagram based on @ThreePhaseEel's comment:*

[image: updated diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This won't fly

What you have proposed is not to Code, due to the current loop created by the "solo" hot wire going up to the fan then returning back via the neutral going down to the other switch.  This violates the intent of the 300.3(B)/310.10(H) prohibitions against current loops and paralleled wires which can create magnetic fields and ensuing eddy-current heating issues in your walls.

### What to do instead

What you should do instead is run 14/3 from the two-gang switch box (fan + light switches) up to the fan box, and then use the 14/3 between the two switch boxes as as a 3-way switch *spur* consisting of two travelers and either an always-hot or a switched-hot as the "return" leg back to where it joins up in the two-gang switch box.  This removes the 14/2 going from the single-gang box up to the fan box, and gets rid of all the magnetic-field issues your original plan had.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, glad I asked! I think I understand. So would the light switch portion of the wiring end up looking like this? [3-way-swtich-light-between2.gif](https://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/3-way-swtich-light-between2.gif)

Comment: @Dan -- basically, yes

Comment: Great. Thanks again!